# When the compiler decides to pad a struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

Let's say we have:

```
struct A{
    char a1;
    char a2;
};

struct B{
    int b1;
    char b2;
};

struct C{
    char C1;
    int C2;
};
```

I know that because of padding to a multiple of the word size (assuming word size=4), `sizeof(C)==8` although `sizeof(char)==1` and `sizeof(int)==4`.

I would expect that `sizeof(B)==5` instead of `sizeof(B)==8`.

But if `sizeof(B)==8` I would expect that `sizeof(A)==4` instead of `sizeof(A)==2`.

Could anyone please explain why the padding and the aligning are working differently in those cases?

Comment: It's highly compiler and architecture-dependent, you know. There's no general answer.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio and set the highest warning level it will point out every instance of padding. Anyway, it seems common for compilers to align along multiples of the largest of primitives (up to a certain point only of course, for GCC it was 4, so ´{double;char;}´ is still 12).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common padding scheme is to pad structs so that each member starts at an even multiple of the size of that member or to the machine word size (whichever is smaller). The entire struct is padded following the same rule.

Assuming such a padding scheme I would expect:

The biggest member in `struct A` has size 1, so no padding is used.

In `struct B`, the size of 5 is padded to 8, because one member has size 4.
The layout would be:

```
int     4
char    1
padding 3
```

In `struct C`, some padding is inserted before the `int`, so that it starts at an address divisible by 4.

The layout would be:

```
char    1
padding 3
int     4
```

Comment: Exactly. The CPU are optimized to access memory aligned adresses. Some old ARM will even generate an [Alignement Fault](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/Babceedc.html) if you try to access non aligned memory data

Comment: Do you have some reference for that? Because in wikipedia it says "Padding is only inserted when a structure member is followed by a member with a larger alignment requirement or at the end of the structure." Which should explain why `struct B` should have `sizeof==5` instead of `sizeof==8` <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding>

Comment: @or.nomore My description doesn't contradict Wikipedia's. My description is a bit more specific, which is why I use the phrase "a common padding scheme". There may be compilers that use other padding schemes.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the compiler to decide how best to pad the struct. For some reason, it decided that in struct B that char b2 was more optimally aligned on a 4 byte boundary.  Additionally, the specific architecture may have requirements/behaviors that the compiler takes into account when deciding how to pad structs.

If you 'pack' the struct, then you'd see the sizes you expect (although that is not portable and may have performance penalties and other issues depending on the architecture).

Answer (score 1):

structs in general will be aligned to boundaries based on the largest type contained. Consider an array of `struct B myarray[5];`

`struct B` must be aligned to 8 bytes so that it's b1 member is always on a 4 byte boundary. `myarray[1].b1` can't start at the 6th byte into the array, which is what you would have if sizeof(B) == 5.

Comment: To put it more directly: Padding is not allowed between array elements. The difference (in bytes) between `a[2]` and `a[3]` is always exactly `sizeof (*a)`.